# Почему не работает условие в if?

Tags: java, строки, if, static

не могу разобраться как в статических методах правильнее описать условие.

3 и 4 условие `if` он сравнивает его объекты и думает что `father` и `mother` `cat` это одно и тоже но как конкретнее описать эти объекты. Так как все остальные условие выполняются верно но и содержания у них одни и те же. А здесь содержание разное так `mother` это дочь `catGrandmother` а `father` это сын `catGrandfather`. По задаче они обязательно все должны быть статическими.

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String grandfatherName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catGrandfather = new Cat(grandfatherName);

        String grandmotherName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catGrandmother = new Cat(grandmotherName);

        String fatherName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catFather = new Cat(fatherName, catGrandfather);

        String motherName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catMother = new Cat(motherName, catGrandmother);

        String sonName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catSon = new Cat(sonName, catMother, catFather);

        String daughterName = reader.readLine();
        Cat catDaughter = new Cat(daughterName, catMother, catFather);

        System.out.println(catGrandfather);
        System.out.println(catGrandmother);
        System.out.println(catFather);
        System.out.println(catMother);
        System.out.println(catSon);
        System.out.println(catDaughter);
    }


    public static class Cat {
    private String name;
    private Cat parent;
    private Cat parent2;

    Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Cat(String name, Cat parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;

    }



    Cat(String name, Cat parent, Cat parent2){
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.parent2 = parent2;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (parent == null)
            return "Cat name is " + name + ", no mother, no father ";
        else if (parent2 == null)
            return "Cat name is " + name + ", no mother, father is " + parent.name;
        else if (parent == null && parent2 == null)
            return "Cat name is " + name + ", mother is " + parent.name +", no father";
        else if (parent2 == null)
            return "Cat name is " + name + ", mother is " + parent.name +", no father";
        else
            return "Cat name is " + name + ", mother is " + parent.name +", father is "+parent2.name;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статика тут не причем. У вас неправильно записано условие.

Теоретически это должно быть правильным:

```
if (parent == null && parent2 == null)
        return "Cat name is " + name + ", no mother, no father ";
    else if (parent2 == null)
        return "Cat name is " + name + ", no mother, father is " + parent.name;
    else if(parent == null)
         return "Cat name is " + name + ", mother is " + parent2.name +", no father";
    else
        return "Cat name is " + name + ", mother is " + parent.name +", father is "+parent2.name;
```

Comment: `if (parent == null)` - даст исключение при попытке обратиться к `parent.name`

Comment: если `parent null` и `parent2 null`, разве не пойдёт по первому выбору `(parent == null)`, хотя должен по `(parent == null && parent2 == null)`? я бы условие с 2 null по матери и отцу вынес как 1-е условие

Comment: @Grundy упс, я и сам запутался там

Comment: @Denis да, вы правы, я исправил

Comment: По поводу класса он в задаче изначально был статическим. Кстати я решаю задачи с  javarush.ru

Comment: *"класс не может быть статическим"* - ещё как может, если это nested class

Comment: @Pavel ааа, ну да. Там первоначально все плохо было с формированием, поэтому не понятно со скобками и что один класс в другом классе